# Which one of these sentences is correct? TO or FOR?

Tags: grammar

I'm quite confused. I feel like both make sense here. Can you guys help me?

I threw a birthday party **TO** my dog

or

I threw a birthday party **FOR** my dog.

Comment: What research did you do? You could for example, search a source (WWW, Google Books ngrams, etc.) for the phrases "birthday party to" and "birthday party for".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I threw a party **for** my dog" is correct. Why?

The reason is about the word "party". "for" is the correct preposition to connect "party" with the purpose of the party, or to the person the party recognizes.

In our case here, the party recognizes the dog, so we say "a party **for** my dog".

The rules for preposition use cannot be derived, but there's often a sensible reason that a particular preposition is the right one. In this case, "for" means "for the benefit of". "I threw a birthday party *for the benefit of* my dog."

The preposition "to", when used with "throw" nearly always indicates a physical movement in that direction, so it would have the nonsense meaning of picking up a party in your hands and throwing it towards your dog.

Answer (score 3):

"for" is correct.

If you use "to," it sounds like you are literally throwing something at the dog. See: "I threw the ball to the dog."